# In Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 check if an IBM-db2 table exists

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to check if a db2 database table (AS400) exists on a Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 within an SQL Server Integrated Services with the query:

if OBJECT_ID (N'"TEURO"."DWH342"',N'U') IS NOT NULL

However, it doesn't work.

Thanks,

Comment: You properbly cant use tsql syntax on a Db2 database

Comment: Thanks for your answer plaidDK but I could use SELECT * from a db2 database table in SSIS as an SQL statement from a table that exists and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes some SQL syntaxes are equal to DB2 but not all

Comment: DB2 for i supports ANSI standard SQL. But it doesn't support Microsoft's TSQL, or Oracle's PL/SQL for that matter. Where TSQL follows ANSI standard, the syntax should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

DB2 doesn't understand TSQL, but you could query the system catalog like this:

```
select * 
  from qsys2.systables
  where table_schema = 'TEURO'
    and table_name = 'DWH342';
```

Comment: This is the way to do it

Comment: Thanks jmarjmurphy, but unfortunately I have to check whether the datatable has been created or not to execute the query

Comment: @RogerGimenezCompta Look more closely at the answer.   I promise you the `systables` table will be there.

Comment: @RogerGimenezCompta the database is always there on IBM i. The only thing that might be missing is the particular schema or table.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: Sorry while executing this query SSIS gives me this error:  
Error at data workflow task DWH342 [ODBC Source [54]]: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '42S22'. Native Error Code: -206. [IBM][ODBC System and Access Controller ][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - SCHEMA_NAME global variable could not be found.TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: I think it should be `table_schema = 'TEURO'`, not `schema_name` -- see [the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstcatalogtbls.htm#catsystbls)

Comment: @RogerGimenezCompta sorry, I had the column name incorrect. It is fixed.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Interestingly, and somewhat disturbingly, it is possible for at least some of the catalog tables to not be available. We have an LPAR where I believe we don't have SYSPARTITIONSTAT or SYSCOLUMNS, as well as a bunch of others. I think it does have SYSTABLES, so maybe your guarantee for that one holds. I'm less confident about anything else, though.

Comment: @JohnY have you consulted IBM on that? It is surprising that any of the documented tables would be missing.

Comment: I haven't talked to IBM. I strongly suspect that whatever is missing is either missing on purpose (because we didn't want to include anything that we didn't "need") or by mistake (because we didn't know what we were doing when we set up that LPAR). Either way, I'm pretty sure it's of our own doing.